# datatables initialize table after button click (ajax, jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have a problem loading datatables object. When I initialize and populate table on page load it works properly.

THIS CODE BELOW WORKS PERFECT AT PAGE RELOAD.

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

$(document).ready(function(){
  var table = $('#dt_110x_complex').DataTable({
    paging : true,
    scrollY: 300,
    ajax: "{{ url_for('complex_data') }}"
  });

});
</script>
```

But this code below DOES NOT WORK on button click. What am I doing wrong?

```
$(function() {
    $('#proces_input').on('click', function() {
        alert('Im in')
        var table = $('#dt_110x_complex').DataTable({
        paging : true,
        scrollY: 300,
        ajax: "{{ url_for('complex_data') }}"
        });

        });
    });
```

The button id = "proces_input". Message alert('Im in') shows after button click.

Below is my html table code (for both samples the same) for datatables.:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
<table id="dt_110x_complex" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>code</th>
<th>date</th>
<th>blocade</th>
<th>konti</th>
<th>free</th>
<th>occ</th>
<th>origin</th>
<th>type</th>
<th>created</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody></tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: from what i could tell (trying it in jsfiddle) it worked (did not load data of cause). Here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/aqk0egy1/1/

Comment: Yes, js script works, but no data recived. In my web browser debuger (firefox) XHR section when page load I get a response (data) but when button click the response is empty and status code is empty, 0 bytes transfered. This can not be server problem :( both ajax request are the same.

Comment: you are not running them both are you? One after the other?

Comment: Yes, I have them both on my website. When page reloads the <table id="dt_110x_complex"> element is populated, then I click button i have another table element <table id="dt_110x_click"> fot testing witch should be populated by the other javascript code (the one with on 'click' event). Of course it coresponds to <table id="dt_110x_click"> element).

Comment: your both table are different ?

Answer (score 3):

As per you commented

> This can not be server problem :( both ajax request are the same.

And If you are Showing data to same table, then there may be **Datatable initialising problem**

If this is so You need to **`destroy`** datatable and **reinitialize** it On buton click:

using  `destroy : true,`

```
$(function() {
    $('#proces_input').on('click', function() {
        alert('Im in')
        var table = $('#dt_110x_complex').DataTable({
            paging : true,
            destroy : true,    <-------Added this 
            scrollY: 300,
            ajax: "{{ url_for('complex_data') }}"
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I made it simple as possible for test. Html code is the same for both options. I run website with first javascript option (the one with $(document).ready(...etc) and it loads data on page reload. The second script (the one with $('#proces_input').on('click',....etc ) and ajax does not return any data after button click. I think i start not to like DataTables :/

Comment: @MaciejskiPawel try adding the destroy option to the first instance of the datatable (the one you initialize on document ready)

Answer (score 2):

If your intention is to reload the data the table is displaying, you could simply use the reload API function from datatables in the click callback:

```
$('#proces_input').on('click', function() {
       table.ajax.reload();
    });
```

`table` should be a global variable though.

If for some reason you need to re-create the table, you should add the `destroy` option to Datatables the first time you create it (i.e.: on document ready), and obviate any option when you re-create the datatable on the click callback:

```
$(function() {
    $('#proces_input').on('click', function() {
        alert('Im in')
        $('#dt_110x_complex').DataTable();
    });
});
```

Comment: Working example of first bit of solution here: https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/ju2bmtm7/

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me after a lot of research:- I have created button with ID "eventlistview" and on click of this re initializing the data table.

```
// global variable
var grid;
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
 //initialise blank datatable on page load
  grid = $('#grd').DataTable({
           "processing": false, // control the processing indicator.
           paging: false,
            searching: false,
            info: false,
          // you can load data here also as per requirement
         });
});

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  jQuery('#eventlistview').click(function () {
     // destroy datatable
     $("#grd").dataTable().fnDestroy()
     //reinitialise datatable
      $("#grd").dataTable({
          "processing": false, // control the processing indicator.
          "serverSide": true, // recommended to use serverSide when data is more than 10000 rows for performance reasons
          "ajax": {"url": "",
                    "type": "GET",
                   },
          "language": {"emptyTable": "No data found."
                      },
           columns: [{ "data": "TitleTxt" },
                      {"data": "StartDate"},
                      {"data": "EndDate"},
                    ],
           "order": [[0, "asc"]]            
                    });          
    });
});
```