# How to load DataTables data on button click

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using this dataTable code to load a table data.

```
var table = $('#fileInfoTable').DataTable({
    "sAjaxSource": "api/file/loadAll",
    "sAjaxDataProp": "",
    "order": [
        [0, "asc"]
    ],
    "aoColumns": [{
        "mData": "fileId"
    }, {
        "mData": "fileName"
    }, {
        "mData": "sentDate"
    }, {
        "mData": "direction"
    }, {
        "mData": "interfaceType"
    }, {
        "mData": "buisnessLine"
    }, {
        "mData": "vaultName"
    }, {
        "mData": "manageCompony"
    }, {
        "mData": "lastActivity"
    }, {
        "mData": "lastActivityStatus"
    }, {
        "mData": "feedbackName"
    }, {
        "mData": "feedbackDate"
    }, {
        "mData": "processDate"
    }, {
        "mData": "eventsAmount"
    }, {
        "mData": "goodEventsAmount"
    }, {
        "mData": "sourceId"
    }]
});
```

It works fine if I load it on page load but I need to be able to load the data by clicking a button and not on page load.
How can I do it?

Edit: now I am using this code below and I can see the alert but the table is undefined

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $('#fileInfoTable').DataTable({
        data: [],
        "order": [
            [0, "asc"]
        ],
        "aoColumns": [{
            "mData": "fileId"
        }, {
            "mData": "fileName"
        }, {
            "mData": "sentDate"
        }, {
            "mData": "direction"
        }, {
            "mData": "interfaceType"
        }, {
            "mData": "buisnessLine"
        }, {
            "mData": "vaultName"
        }, {
            "mData": "manageCompony"
        }, {
            "mData": "lastActivity"
        }, {
            "mData": "lastActivityStatus"
        }, {
            "mData": "feedbackName"
        }, {
            "mData": "feedbackDate"
        }, {
            "mData": "processDate"
        }, {
            "mData": "eventsAmount"
        }, {
            "mData": "goodEventsAmount"
        }, {
            "mData": "sourceId"
        }]
    })

    $("#loadData").on('click', function () {
        alert("ppp:" + table.name);
        table.ajax.url("api/file/loadAll").load();
    })
});
```

Comment: Look at the api.ajax.reload() method. Not entirely clear what button is for and if it is for  reload, changing url params or building table first time

Comment: Try take your code out of this `$(document).ready(function() {` s*** :) I cannot know for sure, but I have the feeling you are making it all too complicated and by that messes up the scope for your variables.

Comment: with out $(document).ready I am not getting the alert at all

Comment: @user7916020, where is the `#loadData` element located..? If it is inside the table, attach the event handler in a [`initComplete`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete) or [`drawCallback`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback) callback. Again, really hard just to guess without more info.

Comment: @davidkonrad ok I will add the html tomorrow. I think the problem is that the loadData  button is not inside a specific div

Comment: @user7916020, My 2 cents: There is three scenarios 1) #loadData is not present in the dom when you define the event handler 2) code for the event handler is for some reason never reached 3) the event handler is not declared properly or #loadData is named something else. I guess you'll see what is wrong as first thing tomorrow :) It often helps to put it away and think about something else, it can be really hard to debug own code because our brain fool us to think the code is exactly as we believe it is (like finding spell errors or bad language in a text you have written 30 secs ago)

Comment: @davidkonrad  can you please explain this code you gave as example :                        $('button').on('click', function() {
  table.ajax.url('https://api.myjson.com/bins/avxod').load();
})         I don't see where in your examle you declare the name or id : 'button  '

Comment: @user7916020, a selector does not *have* to be a specific `id`, if you target `button` all `<button>`'s is targeted. It was just laziness, there is only one `<button>` in he demo, so I do not have to give it an `id` or anything else to identify it, I know the handler will target the one and only `<button>` on the page. Sry for the confusion, did not think about that as something to care about.

Comment: were you able to solve your problem @user7916020

Answer (score 1):

Look at the code below.

**Add Row** [API](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add())

Adding new data to a table is central to the concept of being able to dynamically control the content of a DataTable, and this method provides the ability to do exactly that. It will add a single row at a time - for the addition of multiple rows, either call this method multiple times or use this method's plural counterpart

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

table.row.add({
    "name": "Tiger Nixon",
    "position": "System Architect",
    "salary": "$3,120",
    "start_date": "2011/04/25",
    "office": "Edinburgh",
    "extn": "5421"
}).draw();
```

**Clear** [API](https://datatables.net/reference/api/clear())

When you perform an action such as adding or deleting a row, changing the sorting, filtering or paging characteristics of the table you'll want DataTables to update the display to reflect these changes. This function is provided for that purpose.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

table
    .clear()
    .draw();
```

see documentation **[DRAW](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw())**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable();

  $("#add").on('click', function() {
    table.row.add([
      "Tiger Nixon",
      "System Architect",
      "Edinburgh",
      "54",
      "2011/04/25",
      "$3,120",
    ]).draw();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<input type="button" name="add" id="add" value="addrow" />

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

i have a example here

HTML

```
 ....
      <body>
            <table id="table_id" class="display"></table>

            <button id="customerSearchButton">CLICK AQUI - WACHIN (RECARGAR)</button>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    ...
```

JS

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function() {

        let table = $("#table_id").DataTable({
          columns: [{ data: "id" }, { data: "name" }, { data: "email" }],
          rowCallback: function(row, data) {},
          filter: true,
          info: false,
          ordering: false,
          processing: true,
          retrieve: true
        });
        $("#customerSearchButton").on("click", function(event) {
          $.ajax({
            url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId=1",
            type: "get"
          })
            .done(function(result) {
              console.log(result);
              table.clear().draw();
              table.rows.add(result).draw();
            })
            .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              // needs to implement if it fails
            });
        });
      });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code solved my purpose which is to load data on button click not on page load. I have created button with ID "eventlistview" and on click of this re initializing the data table.

```
// global variable
var grid;
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
 //initialise blank datatable on page load
  grid = $('#grd').DataTable({
           "processing": false, // control the processing indicator.
           paging: false,
            searching: false,
            info: false,
          // you can load data here also as per requirement
         });
});

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  jQuery('#eventlistview').click(function () {
     // destroy datatable
     $("#grd").dataTable().fnDestroy()
     //reinitialise datatable
      $("#grd").dataTable({
          "processing": false, // control the processing indicator.
          "serverSide": true, // recommended to use serverSide when data is more than 10000 rows for performance reasons
          "ajax": {"url": "",
                    "type": "GET",
                   },
          "language": {"emptyTable": "No data found."
                      },
           columns: [{ "data": "TitleTxt" },
                      {"data": "StartDate"},
                      {"data": "EndDate"},
                    ],
           "order": [[0, "asc"]]            
                    });          
    });
});
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58976439/5685144

Hope it helps you too.